# How to Format Parameter Values in MS Access Report Header

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm creating reports in MS Access 2010.  The reports are based off of queries saved in the same database.  When run the reports prompt the user for parameters.  The user will either enter a set of dates for a range, or a set of currency values for a currency range.

I want to show the range input by the user in the report header.  I've done so by adding a TextBox and changing the Control Source to '=[Reports]![ReportName]![ParameterPromptText]' (using my actual report name and prompt text of course).

However, I want to show the data in the 'mm/dd/yyyy' format and show the currency as a currency.  When I change the TextBox's properties to either of those formats, respectively, it only shows the text as the user input it.  So if the user put in a date of 1/12/05, it will not change it to 01/12/2015.  Also for currency, if the user enters 100 it will show 100, not $100.00.

Am I missing something?  How do you change this formatting?  It seems like it'd be easy, so I hope I'm overlooking something basic.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try the Format VBA function, which can do all the formatting for dates and currency you are looking for.  You may need to dice up your original string and concatenate it back together, but should work.

Comment: @VBlades - Thank you for the feedback.   However I can't get that to work anywhere.  How and where do I place that VBA code?  Is my code simply:  TextBoxName.Format "mm/dd/yyyy"?  Thanks.

Comment: Here's the documentation on the function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251755%28v=office.15%29.aspx.  In your text box, the ControlSource would need to be something like =Format([MyField], "mm/dd/yyyy").  Hope that helps.

Comment: @VBlades - Thank you, that did the trick.  I literally had just come up with a work around for it when I saw your answer, but it's not worth mentioning how I did it as your way is easier, and obviously, the correct way to do it.  Thanks again.